# clearing an object of type 'struct ' with no trivial copy-assignment; use assignment or value-initialization instead

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, memset

I am working on a module containing C and C++ codes. The problem is that I am getting the following forbidden warning. I provided the code that Is causing that warning.

```
warning: 'void* memset(void*, int, size_t)' clearing an object of type 'struct OtherStructure_s ' with no trivial copy-assignment; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]\n")
```

---

```
struct TEST {
  explicit TEST();
  OtherStructure_s _otherStructure;
};

TEST::TEST(){
  memset(&_otherStructure, 0, sizeof(OtherStructure_s));
}
```

What is the best solution to remove that warning? If I initialize the structure in the constructor as if
`TEST::TEST():_otherStructure(){}` will that be a good solution?

Comment: The reason for your problem: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Trivial_copy_assignment_operator. You don't need `TEST::TEST():_otherStructure(){}`. The default constructor of `TEST` will default construct `_otherStructure`. The best solution is to remove the constructor.

Comment: @ThomasSablik What if OP needs the value initialisation instead?

Comment: @eerorika There is no compile error. There is a default constructor. Obviously OP tries to default initialize the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OtherStructure_s` doesn't have a [trivial copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Trivial_copy_assignment_operator). You can't use `memset`. Probably the class allocates some other resources like heap memory.

You don't need `TEST::TEST():_otherStructure(){}`. The default constructor of `TEST` will default construct `_otherStructure`. The best solution is to remove the constructor.